# Process level view on Flowable

Tags: spring-boot, workflow, flowable

I am currently working on a project where I have integrated Flowable, an open-source workflow management system, to handle workflow capabilities. I am exploring options to visualize the process flow at a high level. Additionally, I am investigating methods to handle dynamic approver names efficiently. Are there any built-in functions or features within Flowable that allow for the retrieval of approvers' lists, especially in cases where approvers are dynamically assigned? Furthermore, I am interested in understanding how to capture the end of a workflow process. Your insights and guidance on these matters would be greatly appreciated.

Any methods or ways of solving the issues or links related to the documentation of the issue

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.